# How to Color Certain cells in TikZ Pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, ifthenelse

I'm interested on coloring certain cells of a TikZ picture. It is the following:

[image: Picture I created]

I did it by using the grid and creating the numbers. I present the code I create above:

> ```
> \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.7]   
>
> \draw[lightgray] (0,0) grid (9,9);
> \draw[blue] (2,2) grid (7,7);
>
> %Ciclo de cuadrado auxiliar
>
> \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4}{
>     \foreach\j in {0,1,2,3,4}{
>         \draw[red,thick,opacity = 0.5] (\i + \j,4 +\j - \i) rectangle (\i + \j + 1, 5 + \j - \i);
>     }
> }
>
> %Cuadrado principal
>
> \draw[blue,opacity = 0.5] (2,2) grid (7,7);              
>
> %Ubicación de números 
>
> \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4}{
>     \foreach \j in {0,1,2,3,4}{
>         
>         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i + \j + 4*\i + 1};
>
>         %\pgfmathparse[3 <= \i <= 5 && 0 <= j <= 1 ? int(1) : int(0)}
>         
>         %\ifnum\pgfmathresult = 1 
>         %\node[teal] at (\i + \j + 0.5,4 +\j - \i + 0.5) {\label};
>         %\else
>         \node at (\i + \j + 0.5,4 +\j - \i + 0.5) {\label};
>         %\fi
>         
>     }
> } \end{tikzpicture}
> ```

Inside the cycle, there are some commented lines. The thing is that I want to color only the number that appears out of the blue square, in fact, the ones that are below it (16,22,21). However, I got multiple errors! It is a list up to 24 errors. I suspect I have a problem with the writting of the condition.

## Questions:

Do you know which are the errors on the condition?
Could you recommend a reference to read about these conditions?

## Update

Sorry for going out, but I'm back. The answer was very helpful, however I need to do some changes to get the expected result. There is an instance of the code and the resulting image

> ```
> \begin{figure}[H]
>     \centering
>     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
>         %\draw[lightgray] (0,0) grid (9,9);
>
>         %Cuadrado auxiliar con desplazados resaltados
>         \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
>             \foreach \j in {0,...,4}{
>                 \draw[red!50,thick] (\i+\j,4+\j-\i) rectangle +(1,1);
>                 \pgfmathparse{\i - \j > 2 ? 1 : 0}
>                 \ifnum\pgfmathresult = 1
>                     \def\mycolor{white}
>                     \node[\mycolor] at (\i+\j+0.5,4+\j-\i+0.5) {\inteval{5*\i+\j+1}};
>                 \else
>                     \pgfmathparse{\j - \i > 2 ? 1 : 0}
>                     \ifnum\pgfmathresult = 1
>                         \def\mycolor{white}
>                         \node[\mycolor] at (\i+\j+0.5,4+\j-\i+0.5) {\inteval{5*\i+\j+1}};
>                     \else
>                         \pgfmathparse{\i + \j < 2 ? 1 : 0}
>                         \ifnum\pgfmathresult = 1
>                             \def\mycolor{cyan}
>                             \node[\mycolor] at (\i+\j+0.5,4+\j-\i+0.5) {\inteval{5*\i+\j+1}};    
>                         \else
>                             \def\mycolor{black}
>                             \node[\mycolor] at (\i+\j+0.5,4+\j-\i+0.5) {\inteval{5*\i+\j+1}};
>                         \fi
>                     \fi
>                 \fi
>                   
>             }
>         }
>         %Cuadrado principal
>         \draw[blue] (2,2) grid (7,7);
>
>         %Resaltado en cuadrado principal de anteriores
>         \node[teal] at (3.5,6.5) {$16$};
>         \node[teal] at (4.5,5.5) {$21$};
>         \node[teal] at (5.5,6.5) {$22$};
>         \node[violet] at (3.5,2.5) {$4$};
>         \node[violet] at (4.5,3.5) {$5$};
>         \node[violet] at (5.5,2.5) {$10$};
>
>         %Ubicacion de numeros nuevos 
>         \draw[->,cyan!50,thick] (1.5,5.5) to (6.5,5.5);
>         \node[cyan] at (6.5,5.5) {$2$};
>
>         \draw[->,cyan!50,thick] (0.5,4.5) to (5.5,4.5);
>         \node[cyan] at (5.5,4.5) {$1$};
>
>         \draw[->,cyan!50,thick] (1.5,3.5) to (6.5,3.5);
>         \node[cyan] at (6.5,3.5) {$6$};
>         
>         \end{tikzpicture}
> ```

[image: A step of my construction]

I did use a different color for each step, I am very grateful for the help. Any ideas about my second question?

Comment: `3 <= \i <= 5` will always be true because 0 ≤ 5 and 1 ≤ 5 since “false” and “true” will just be interpreted as zero and one.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I am new with TikZ, thanks for being clear about the condition, do you know how to change the notation to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the code in the question:

- The `[` after `\pgfmathparse` should be `{`.
- The usage of multiple `<=` in one condition of `\pgfmathparse` can lead to unexpected results.
- Inside `\pgfmathparse`, one `j` should be `\j`.
- The `int(1)` can be replaced by `1` and `int(0)` by `0`.
- With `\foreach`, `0,1,2,3,4` can be replaced by `0,...,4`.
- After `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, no `;` is required.

The condition in `\pgfmathparse` has been changed.

First, the color is defined. Then the code for the node only needs to be placed once instead of twice.

By using `\inteval`, it is unnecessary to define `\label` with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

The code for the squares can be simplified with `rectangle +(1,1)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}%not necessary from 2022-06-01: see https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw[lightgray] (0,0) grid (9,9);
\draw[blue] (2,2) grid (7,7);
\foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
  \foreach \j in {0,...,4}{
    \pgfmathparse{\i+\j<2||\i+\j>6||\i-\j>2||\j-\i>2?1:0}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
      \def\mycolor{teal}
      \draw[red!50,thick] (\i+\j,4+\j-\i) rectangle +(1,1);
    \else
      \def\mycolor{black}
    \fi
    \node[\mycolor] at (\i+\j+0.5,4+\j-\i+0.5) {\inteval{5*\i+\j+1}};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your answer. All your advices are very helpful for my learning of TikZ